# Uninitialized local variable 'state' used

Tags: visual-c++

So I want to create a program which allows users to map buttons to keyboard presses using c++ with Visual Studio 2015. I have been having a ton of trouble with Xinput and I was hoping someone could help me with one simple problem which makes no sense seeing as I have defined it.

So my problem is I get one error which says unresolved external symbol _XinputGetState@8 referenced in function _main.

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Xinput.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    XINPUT_STATE state;
    ZeroMemory(&state, sizeof(XINPUT_STATE));

    if (XInputGetState(0, &state) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
    cout << "It worked!" << endl;
    }

    bool A_button_pressed = ((state.Gamepad.wButtons & XINPUT_GAMEPAD_A) != 0);
    cout << A_button_pressed << endl;
}
```

Comment: `XInputGetState` **requires** `Xinput.lib` and `Xinput9_1_0.lib`. Did you add them to your project on setttings? Try using `#pragma comment(lib, "Xinput.lib")` and  `#pragma comment(lib, "Xinput9_1_0.lib")` just below your `include`s ( XInput.h)

Comment: @ViniyoShouta thank you very much it worked!

Comment: glad I could help! If you want you can accept the answer below, so this question does have one. If something similar ever happens to you again, you can google the particular function with unresolved external symbols and check which libraries are needed in case you don't know them.

Comment: Thank you, @ViniyoShouta spent so long last night searching how to mark a comment as an answer lol!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general `unresolved external symbols` means that a library needed for the function is not linked.

In this case:

`XInputGetState()` **requires** `XInputLib.lib` and `Xinput9_1_0.lib`.

This can be resolved by adding the libraries in the project settings or via:

`#pragma comment(lib,"XInput.lib")`

`#pragma comment(lib,"Xinput9_1_0.lib")`